# Mapping values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, union

I have a query similar to the following (removed a lot of irrelevant junk as it's more of a concept question):

```
SELECT o_prop.*
FROM o
LEFT JOIN o_prop
ON o_prop.id = o.id
```

The output looks something like this:

```
name      | value
bank_name | My Bank
bank_date | 12-12-12
bank_name | My Bank2
bank_date | 13-12-12
```

But I need the following output:

```
bank_name | bank_date
My Bank   | 12-12-12
My Bank2  | 13-12-12
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Can you please give a more precise example of tables structure ?

Comment: well, the best way would be on application layer. But if you want to do it in mysql itself, have a look at pivot(ing) - a good read is this post http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,75357,75357#msg-75357

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'bank_name' THEN p.value ELSE NULL END) bank_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'bank_date' THEN p.value ELSE NULL END) bank_date
FROM    o
        LEFT JOIN o_oprop p
            ON o.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

From your output, it seems to me you're using something like an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), or am I mistaken? If that's the case, it's not really a good idea to do it in SQL, better do it in the application layer as @Najzero suggested (pivoting will not work in this case).

If you **really** need it in SQL, then check [@JW.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936866/520779), it will do what you need in this case. However, in most scenarios besides this simple query (when you need to use EAV and can't do a proper table model) it might perform poorly, cause data inconsistencies or not be possible at all. Keeping things simple might be a "saner" way of dealing with such systems in the end.

Comment: Sadly, it's not possible to do it in the application layer as it's feeding into a third party reporting application!

Comment: @andy JW.'s answer will suffice then. Just note that the `o` join is unnecessary (since none of its columns is appearing in the output), unless there are rows in `o_oprop` without a corresponding row in `o`.

Comment: It does kind of work, but there's other joins on the query and it selects 100+ fields with * that are needed (That wasn't my decision! haha.) So doing `SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN...` produces a syntax error. I'm not sure how to get around it without manually listing every field in the select.

Comment: @andy well, that's the problem with EAV... you can't `select *` because `group by` doesn't let you access individual values, only aggregations. Listing every field might be your only way to go then (but instead of typing all them, you could generate it with a script).

Comment: Yay! I've figured out a different way of doing it. It's messy but it'll do. Basically just a subquery: `SELECT (SELECT o_prop.value FROM o WHERE o.id = xxx) AS bank_name`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to select something like that:

```
SELECT o.bank_name, o_prop.bank_date
```

Anyway, could you describe your tables? (enumerate their fields)

Comment: In the end I would like to be able to do that yes! It's just 3 columns in o_prop `id`, `name`, `value` and I want to be able to select `value` using `name` if that makes any sense? Sorry if not, I have no idea how to phrase this.